# Best way to reference two associated models in the third model in Django

Tags: django

I need to reference `Category` and `SubCategory` models in the `Product` model. But `SubCategory` has a `ForeignKey` to `Category`. Right now I am referencing as shown below. Is there a better way or is this correct?

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.category_name}'

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.subcategory_name}'

class Product(models.Model):
    company_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    company_subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends, can `product.company_category` be different than `product.company_subcategory.category`, if the answer is yes then your current setup is correct.

But if those two values will always be the same and you want to keep your tables as normalized as possible, then it might be a good idea to only use `company_subcategory`.

One caveat to the normalized approach is every time you load an instance of `Product` and you want to reach `product.company_subcategory.category` you will generate extra sql queries unless you use the [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) or [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) methods

```
Product.objects.all().prefetch_related('company_subcategory', 'company_subcategory__category')
Product.objects.select_related('company_subcategory', 'company_subcategory__category').get(pk=1)
```

Comment: A subcategory of a product always belongs to the same category. In the form, I should create a chained dropdown wherein first the category is selected and only then the subcategories belonging to that category are populated in the next dropdown. So can I use both fields in the form if I use normalized approach?

Comment: yes, you can add the category field to your `ModelForm` as a `ModelChoiceField`, `category = forms.ModelChoiceField(Category.objects.all())` and then have the js on the frontend filter the subcategory field based on the category field selection. When the `ModelForm` is saved, the category field is ignored and only the subcategory is saved.

Comment: Ok. Got it. What if I should give an option for the user if that category is not present? Does this still work?

Comment: sounds like that is a case where category is different than subcategory.category, if it is, then you should go with your initial design. Else if you want to ignore category in this case and still have a subcategory, then you can create a default subcategory and use it when you don't have any matches for the category.

Comment: Actually for this case, I was thinking of giving the user the option of giving input to category and subcategory and then in backend create category first and then create subcategory and give it the id of the recently created category as reference.